# Rewrite this code using easydict. Argparse is not working properly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, argparse

I have the following code :

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", type=str,help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-east", "--east", type=str,help="path to input EAST text detector")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--min-confidence", type=float, default=0.5,help="minimum probability required to inspect a region")
ap.add_argument("-w", "--width", type=int, default=320,help="resized image width (should be multiple of 32)")

ap.add_argument("-e", "--height", type=int, default=320,help="resized image height (should be multiple of 32)")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

The problem is that I get the following error :

```
 usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-i IMAGE] [-east EAST] [-c MIN_CONFIDENCE]
                             [-w WIDTH] [-e HEIGHT]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-e147c702-ba2b-4876-a2d6-01454f32f612.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3339: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

Comment: You cannot use commandline arguments with a notebook.  Those unrecognized arguments are ones used by the notebook launcher, and meaningless to your `argparse` usage.  This isn't just an `argparse` issue.

Comment: Can you suggest any method for notebook?

Comment: The notebook should allow you to provide arguments interactively.  The arguments supplied when starting the Server are intended for the server itself, not your notebook.   The server can handle multiple notebooks. If you don't like this, don't use a notebooks.  Run your code as a Python script.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this `argparse`?  And why the `easydict` question?  What's the connection?

Comment: I was trying to rewrite this code using easy dict. https://qiita.com/LittleWat/items/6e56857e1f97c842b261 .

Comment: `easydict` would let you make an `argparse.Namespace` like object, the kind you get from `parse_args`.  But your use of `vars()` converts that to a dictionary.  Just create the relevant dictionary, and forget the `argparse` and commandline input.